# Angular: Using Renderer2 sporadically returning a RendererAdapter instance instead of DefaultDomRenderer2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I have a component which injects the Renderer2 module. I'm using this component in several places, and it works just fine in every instance except one. On that one instance, I drilled down to find out that it is returning a `RendererAdapter` object, as opposed to the `DefaultDomRenderer2` object that gets returned in every other instance. See screenshot below. Any idea why this one instance would be different?

```
import {Component, Input, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

...

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.renderer);
  }

}
```

[image]